# is it possible to markup all programming languages under object oriented paradigm using a common markup schema?

Tags: programming-languages, metaprogramming, code-generation

i have planned to develop a tool that converts a program written in a programming language ***(eg: Java)*** to a common markup language ***(eg: XML)*** and that markup code is converted to another language ***(eg: C#)***.

> ***in simple words, it is a programming language converter that converts program written in one language to another language.***

i think it is possible but i don know where to start. i wanna know the possibilities to do so and information about some existing system.

Comment: I hope it can translate Whitespace to Ook..

Comment: That is what we call a compiler - writing one is not easy, but see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler for resources.

Comment: No. It is not possible (mathematically and practically). Really, it is not,not in any useful and practical way, specially if you are trying to use XML. If you doubt this, try to convert this C statement ('void * p = 1; p++`) or an assembly statement (`mov ax, 1234h`) into BASIC or JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is extremely hard, but if you want to know what you are up for I've listed the steps you need to follow below:

First the hard bit:

1. First you obtain or derive an operational semantics for your source and target languages.
2. Then you enhance the semantics to capture your source and target memory models.
3. Then you need to unify the two enhanced-semantics within a common operational model.
4. Then you need to define a mapping from your source languages onto the common operational model.
5. Then you need to define a mapping from your operational model to your target language

Step 4, as you pointed out in your question, is trivial.
Step 1 is difficult, as most languages do not have sufficiently formal semantics specified; but I recommend checking out http://lucacardelli.name/TheoryOfObjects.html as this is the best starting point for building a traditional OO semantics.
Step 2 is almost certainly impossible in general, but may be merely obscenely difficult if you are willing to sacrifice some efficiency.
Step 3 will depend on how clean the result of step 1 turned out, but is going to be anything from delicate and tricky to impossible.
Step 5 is not going to be trivial, it is effectively writing a compiler.

Ultimately, what you propose to do is impossible in general, due to the difficulties inherited in steps 1 and 2. However it should be difficult, but doable, if you are willing to: severely restrict the source language constructs supported; pretty much forget handling threads correctly; and pick two languages with sufficiently similar semantics (ie. Java and C# are ok, but C++ and anything-else is not).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what languages you want to support, but in general this is a huge & difficult task unless you plan to only support a very small subset of each language.

The real problem is that each programming languages has different features (with some areas that overlap and others that don't) and different ways of solving the same problems -- and it's pretty tricky to detect the problem the programmer is trying to solve and convert that to a new idiom.  :)  And think about the differences between GUIs created in different languages....

See http://xmlvm.org/ as an example (a project aimed at converting between source code of many different languages, with an XML middle-point) -- the site covers in some depth the challenges they are tackling and the compromises they take, and (if you still have any interest in this kind of project...) ask more specific followup questions.

Notice specifically what the output source code looks like -- it's not at all readable, maintainable, efficient, etc..

Comment: thanks rob, i ve started to model the system.. i'll let you know the progress of the project. :-)

Comment: You'll note that the "XMLVM" representation is *different* for each target.

Answer (score 2):

It is "technically easy" to produce XML for any single langauge: build a parser, construct and abstract syntax tree, and dump out that tree as XML.  (I build tools that do this off-the-shelf for many languages).   By technically easy, I mean that the community knows how to do this (see any compiler textbook, e.g., Aho&Ullman Dragon book).  I do not mean this is a trivial exercise in terms of effort, because real languages are complicated and messy; there have been many attempts to build C++ parsers and few successes. (I have one of the successes, and it was expensive to get right).

What is really hard (and I don't try to do) is produce XML according to a single schema in which the language semantics are exposed.  And without that, it will be essentially impossible to write a translator from a *generic* XML to an arbitrary target language.  This is known as the [UNCOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNCOL) problem and people have been looking since 1958 for the answer.  I note that the Wikipedia article seems to indicate the problem is solved, but you can't find many references to UNCOL in the literature since 1961.

The closest attempt I've seen to this is the OMG's "ASTM" model (http://www.omg.org/spec/ASTM/1.0/Beta1/); it exports XMI which is XML.   But the ASTM model has lots of escapes built into it to allow langauges that it doesn't model perfectly (AFAIK, that means *every* language) to extend the XMI in arbitrary ways so that the language-specific information can be encoded.  Consequently each language parser produces a custom version of the XMI, and thus each reader has to pretty much know about the extensions and full generality vanishes.